# How to append an array inside an array?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of working hours, and within that array, there is another array of shifts. I would like to remove all instances in the shifts array where weekday is equal to "Monday"

```
struct Shift {
    let id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var weekday: String
    var startTime: String
    var endTime: String
    var error: Bool
}

struct WorkingHours: Identifiable {
    let id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var availability: [Shift]
}

class AvailabilityManager: ObservableObject {

    @Published var workingHours: [WorkingHours] = []
    
}
```

In my view:

```
@EnvironmentObject var availabilityManager: AvailabilityManager

self.availabilityManager.workingHours.removeAll(where: {$0.availability.weekday == "Monday"})
```

However, it says: "Value of type '[Shift]' has no member 'weekday'"

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: You need a `forEach` for each `workingHours` and a `forEach` for each `Shift` in availability`. A nested loop, you will find help if you search that term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
self.availabilityManager.workingHours.removeAll(where: {$0.availability.weekday == "Monday"})
```

To

```
self.availabilityManager.workingHours.removeAll(where: {$0.availability.contains(where: {$0.weekday == "Monday"})})
```

More shorthand method

```
self.availabilityManager.workingHours.removeAll { $0.availability.contains { $0.weekday == "Monday" } }
```

Comment: @devOP1, this answer is incorrect since it will remove all instances of WorkingHours that contains a Shift for Monday rather than removing only the Shift object that has weekDay == "Monday"

Answer (score 0):

Add the following function to `WorkingHours`

```
mutating func removeShift(weekDay: String) {
    availability = availability.filter { $0.weekday != weekDay }
}
```

and call it like

```
workingHour.removeShift(weekDay: "Monday")
```

If you have an array of `WorkinHours` you can call the method using `map` for instance

```
workingHoursArray = workingHoursArray.map {
    var workingHours = $0
    workingHours.removeShift(weekDay: "Monday")
    return workingHours
}
```